# as3 / flex interface incompatibility when loading external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, external

I have a main project, and i want to load another project's swf into it:

```
//loader code in Main class of main project
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../src/components/TextTool.swf");      
var ttWrapper:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
var ldr:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader(); 
var context:LoaderContext   = new LoaderContext();
if (Security.sandboxType == Security.LOCAL_TRUSTED) {
context.applicationDomain   = new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
    }         ldr.source = "../src/components/TextTool.swf";
        ldr.loaderContext = context;
        ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
        ldr.load();     
        can.addElement(ldr);
```

Here's the code of the Main class of the second project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:stark="stark.*" name="textModule" >    
        <stark:TextTool name="myTF" id="myTF"></stark:TextTool>
    </s:Application>
```

Now both of the projects contain an interface file : IModule, with the same code, and an element of the second project (the one that's being loaded) which is an instance of my custom class "TextTool", which extends s:Group and implements IModule:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400"
        xmlns:com="src"
        height="130" creationComplete = "initText()" implements="IModule"></s:Group>
```

Now as soon as i've loaded the swf, i want to access that TextTool instance which has and id of "myTF" :

```
//Code in the main class of the main project
    trace(getQualifiedClassName(mySwf.getChildByName('textModule')['myTF']));
    trace(mySwf.getChildByName('textModule')['myTF'] is IModule);
    //output:

    //stark::TextTool
    //false
```

As i've mentioned above, i have the interface in both projects, same code, it has the same path relative to main classes, and myTF does extend IModule. After the swf is loaded, i get the right element, but i still get false when verifying if it implements IModule.
Why?

Comment: Does 'textModule' show that it implements anything? I wonder if the compiler has renamed one or both to prevent a collision in memory.

Comment: 'textModule' doesn't implement IModule, what did you expect the compiler to rename?

Answer (score 0):

You're testing `Application` for implementation

```
trace(mySwf.getChildByName('textModule') is IModule);
```

I think you forgot to add `['myTF']`

```
trace(mySwf.getChildByName('textModule')['myTF'] is IModule);
```

Comment: My bad. Looks like i deleted `["myTF"]` when testing before copy/pasting it into the message. Fixed.

Comment: I've made a small example (i use FlashDevelop), [http://au.optimum-web.com:8080/pub/alex/loader_test.rar] here is the zip, if you could take a couple of minutes and see what i'm doing wrong? (click the stage when the loaded swf is added, and you'll se the trace).

Answer (score 0):

You're loading both into different ApplicationDomains, so whichever loads first wins. Try loading them into the same ApplicationDomain.

Comment: i've changed the `if (Security.sandboxType == Security.LOCAL_TRUSTED) {` to `context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;` to give the loader's context the current app domain, but still no success. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I'm talking about this line var context:LoaderContext   = new LoaderContext(); If you get rid of that and don't use that parameter, what happens?

Comment: Still returns false. I've tried everything using this  [senocular's tutorial](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/?page=2).  But i made it work. I merged both projects, so they would use 1 interface file, instead of two separate files, although they had identical package, name and code. Still, it's very uncomfortable to work a project with such structure, and what if a person makes a module using my interface and then just sends me the swf?